# Does ksonnet have a similar function like "helm list"?

Tags: kubernetes-helm, ksonnet

I used 'helm chart' before, and started to learn ksonnet recently. After reading https://ksonnet.io/docs/cli-reference#overview, I am confused that  there is no "helm list" function in ksonnet. Please correct me if I misunderstand. And if my understanding is correct, please let me know why.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is

```
ks registry list
```

to list configured registries and

```
ks pkg list
```

which will list known packages.

Comment: But how to list the `running` deployment?

Comment: You can use `ks diff default` to diff the local configuration against the cluster's configuration. ksonnet can only report what the server says is running.